# Session not getting created after upgrading to hibernate 5

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I have the following code in my `HibernateUtil` class. But when trying to call the `getSession()` method getting the following

```
error.org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Could not initialize class packagepath/HbernateUtil
```

*HibernateUtil.java*

```
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
}    


public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    getSessionFactory().close();
}
```

*DAOImpl.java*

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

This is how i am trying to get the session, but then i got the above mentioned error. Can anyone please tell what is going wrong here.

Stacktrace

```
13:07:31,553 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52) org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]   

2019-02-08 13:07:31,553 ERROR [stderr]  - org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

13:07:31,562 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,562 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)

13:07:31,566 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,566 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)

13:07:31,570 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,570 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)

13:07:31,574 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,574 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)

13:07:31,578 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,578 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)

13:07:31,583 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,583 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)

13:07:31,587 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,587 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)

13:07:31,591 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,591 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)

13:07:31,594 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,594 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)

13:07:31,598 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,598 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)

13:07:31,602 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:417)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,602 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:417)

13:07:31,607 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:86)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,607 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:86)

13:07:31,611 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,611 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)

13:07:31,617 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,617 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)

13:07:31,621 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,621 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)

13:07:31,625 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:12)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,625 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:12)

13:07:31,629 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.DAOImpl.mathodName(AssetPanelDAOImpl.java:112)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,629 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.DAOImpl.methodName(AssetPanelDAOImpl.java:112)

13:07:31,633 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.DAOImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d89f8c6c.invoke(<generated>)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,633 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.DAOImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d89f8c6c.invoke(<generated>)

13:07:31,637 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,637 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)

13:07:31,641 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,641 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)

13:07:31,645 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,645 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)

13:07:31,649 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.AroundLogPrint.logPerformanceStats(AroundLogPrint.java:21)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,649 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.AroundLogPrint.logPerformanceStats(AroundLogPrint.java:21)

13:07:31,653 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.AroundInterceptor.invoke(WebAround.java:10)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,653 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.interceptors.AroundInterceptor.invoke(WebAround.java:10)

13:07:31,657 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,657 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

13:07:31,661 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,661 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)

13:07:31,665 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.DAOImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8a6ac3d3.methodName(<generated>)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,665 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.DAOImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8a6ac3d3.methodName(<generated>)

13:07:31,669 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.ServiceImpl.methodName(AssetPanelServiceImpl.java:73)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,669 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.ServiceImpl.methodName(AssetPanelServiceImpl.java:73)

13:07:31,673 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.ServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$65313ef2.invoke(<generated>)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,673 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.ServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$65313ef2.invoke(<generated>)

13:07:31,677 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,677 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)

13:07:31,681 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,681 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)

13:07:31,685 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,685 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)

13:07:31,689 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.AroundLogPrint.logPerformanceStats(AroundLogPrint.java:21)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,689 ERROR [stderr]  -   at package.AroundLogPrint.logPerformanceStats(AroundLogPrint.java:21)

13:07:31,693 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at package.WebAround.invoke(WebAround.java:10)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,693 ERROR [stderr]  -   at package.WebAround.invoke(WebAround.java:10)

13:07:31,697 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,697 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

13:07:31,700 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,700 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)

13:07:31,705 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.ServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7b289f25.methodName(<generated>)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,705 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.ServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7b289f25.methodName(<generated>)

13:07:31,709 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.controller.methodName(AssetPanelController.java:163)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,709 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.controller.methodName(AssetPanelController.java:163)

13:07:31,713 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.controller.Controller$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f96285f8.invoke(<generated>)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,713 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.controller.Controller$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f96285f8.invoke(<generated>)

13:07:31,717 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,717 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)

13:07:31,721 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,721 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)

13:07:31,725 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,725 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)

13:07:31,730 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at package.AroundLogPrint.logPerformanceStats(AroundLogPrint.java:21)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,730 ERROR [stderr]  -   at package.AroundLogPrint.logPerformanceStats(AroundLogPrint.java:21)

13:07:31,734 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at package.WebAround.invoke(WebAround.java:10)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,734 ERROR [stderr]  -   at package.WebAround.invoke(WebAround.java:10)

13:07:31,738 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,738 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

13:07:31,742 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,742 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)

13:07:31,746 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.controller.Controller$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$76e607f7.methodName(<generated>)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,746 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.controller.Controller$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$76e607f7.methodName(<generated>)

13:07:31,750 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,750 ERROR [stderr]  -   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

13:07:31,754 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,754 ERROR [stderr]  -   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

13:07:31,758 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,758 ERROR [stderr]  -   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

13:07:31,762 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,762 ERROR [stderr]  -   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

13:07:31,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,766 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)

13:07:31,770 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,770 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)

13:07:31,774 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,774 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)

13:07:31,778 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,778 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)

13:07:31,782 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,782 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)

13:07:31,786 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,786 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)

13:07:31,790 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,790 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)

13:07:31,794 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,794 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)

13:07:31,798 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,798 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)

13:07:31,802 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,802 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)

13:07:31,806 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,806 ERROR [stderr]  -   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)

13:07:31,810 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,810 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)

13:07:31,815 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,815 ERROR [stderr]  -   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

13:07:31,819 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,819 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

13:07:31,823 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,823 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)

13:07:31,827 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,827 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)

13:07:31,832 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,832 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)

13:07:31,835 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,835 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)

13:07:31,839 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,839 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)

13:07:31,843 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,843 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)

13:07:31,847 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,847 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

13:07:31,851 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at packagepath.Filter.methodName(PrivilegeCheckFilter.java:78)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,851 ERROR [stderr]  -   at packagepath.Filter.methodName(PrivilegeCheckFilter.java:78)

13:07:31,855 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,855 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)

13:07:31,859 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,859 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

13:07:31,864 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,864 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)

13:07:31,868 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,868 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

13:07:31,872 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,872 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

13:07:31,876 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,876 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

13:07:31,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,880 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

13:07:31,885 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,885 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)

13:07:31,890 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,890 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

13:07:31,894 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,894 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

13:07:31,898 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,898 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

13:07:31,902 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,902 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

13:07:31,906 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,906 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

13:07:31,910 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,910 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

13:07:31,915 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,915 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

13:07:31,919 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,919 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

13:07:31,923 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,923 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

13:07:31,927 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,927 ERROR [stderr]  -   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

13:07:31,931 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,931 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

13:07:31,935 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,935 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

13:07:31,939 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,939 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)

13:07:31,942 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)

2019-02-08 13:07:31,942 ERROR [stderr]  -   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)

13:07:31,946 ERROR [stderr] (default task-52)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
```

Comment: Why are you you swallowing exceptions in `buildSessionFactory` ?

Comment: Change this `catch (Exception e) { }` to this `catch (Throwable th) {th.printStackTrace();}` and add the stack trace to the question.

Comment: Stacktrace has been added @v.ladynev

Comment: It is need a stack trace provided by this call `th.printStackTrace()`. The stack trace provided by you is useless.

Comment: Stacktrace as you said has been updated @v.ladynev

Comment: Now it is better: ` org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]`. But we need a 'cause`. Probably you added not all stack trace. Also you can do `th.getStackTrace().printStackTrace()` or use a debugger.